# Information Matrix for Conditional Likelihood

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, expected-value, fisher-information, hessian

I am studying the MLE theory on my own and I am confused by the difference between the fisher information matrix for the full sample and for one observation, when it comes to conditional likelihood. However, I think that I have understood the i.i.d. case. I start with a description of the i.i.d. case.

### IID Observations

Assume that we have $T$ i.i.d. random variables with density $f(x_t;\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and the usual regularity conditions hold. The MLE maximizes the log-likelihood-function:
\begin{align}
\ln {\cal L}(\boldsymbol{\theta})= \ln\left(\prod_{t=1}^Tf(x_t;\boldsymbol{\theta})\right)=\sum_{t=1}^T\ln(f(x_t;\boldsymbol{\theta}))=\sum_{t=1}^T\ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align}
The FOC's are given by:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln {\cal L}(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}\left[\sum_{t=1}^T\ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})\right]=\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{\partial \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}=\boldsymbol{0}
\end{align}
In most books the following discussion seems to be based on $\frac{\partial \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}$, rather than $\frac{\partial \ln {\cal L}(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}$. I understand the derivation of the following results:

1. The expected value of the score vector of the $t$-th observation is $\boldsymbol{0}$, i.e. $E\left(\frac{\partial \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$.
2. We can express the information matrix for the $t$-th observation as
   \begin{align}
   \boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})=E\left(\frac{\partial \ell_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}} \frac{\partial \ell_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}'}\right)=-E\left( \frac{\partial ^2 \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}'} \right)
   \end{align}
   and since we have i.i.d. observations, the result is the same for all $t$. So I write for simplification $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})=\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$.

I also know that for $T\rightarrow \infty$, the following results hold:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{T}(\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}-\boldsymbol{\theta}_0)\overset{L}{\rightarrow}N(\boldsymbol{0};\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}(\boldsymbol{\theta_0})^{-1})
\end{align}
Or equivalent:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\overset{L}{\rightarrow}N(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0;\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_T(\boldsymbol{\theta_0})^{-1})
\end{align}
Where $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ is the true parameter vector, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ is the MLE and $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_T(\boldsymbol{\theta_0})$ is the information matrix of the full sample evaluated at $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$. Since the random variables are i.i.d., it holds that $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_T(\boldsymbol{\theta})=T\cdot\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$.

### Conditional Case

Now I want to extend these results to the case where we have to work with the conditional likelihood (for example, time series models).
Assume that we observe the variables $\left\{x_t\right\}_{t=1}^T$ which are dependent. Suppose that the conditional density of the $t$-th observation, conditioned on $\Omega_{t-1}=\left\{x_{t-1},\dots,x_1\right\}$, is given by $f(x_t\vert \Omega_{t-1};\boldsymbol{\theta})$.
The conditional log-likelihood function is given by:
\begin{align}
\ln {\cal L}(\boldsymbol{\theta})= \ln\left(\prod_{t=1}^Tf(x_t \vert \Omega_{t-1};\boldsymbol{\theta})\right)=\sum_{t=1}^T\ln(f(x_t \vert \Omega_{t-1};\boldsymbol{\theta}))=\sum_{t=1}^T\ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})
\end{align}
I tried to  derive the same statements as above and I am not sure whether they are true or not:

1. The expected value of the score vector of the $t$-th observation conditioned on $\Omega_{t-1}$ is $\boldsymbol{0}$, i.e.  $E\left(\frac{\partial \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}\vert \Omega_{t-1}\right)=\boldsymbol{0}$.
2. We can express the information matrix for the $t$-th observation as
   \begin{align}
   \boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})=E\left(\frac{\partial \ell_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}} \frac{\partial \ell_t(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}'} \vert \Omega_{t-1}\right)=-E\left( \frac{\partial ^2 \ell_t (\boldsymbol{\theta})}{\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}'} \vert \Omega_{t-1} \right)
   \end{align}
   However, since we are conditioning on $\Omega_{t-1}$, I think that $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_i(\boldsymbol{\theta}) \neq \boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_j(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ for $i \neq j$.

Now my final question: Are these two statements correct ? And how do I calculate the equivalent of $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and especially $\boldsymbol{{\cal I}}_T(\boldsymbol{\theta})$, so that I can derive the asymptotic distributions ?

Comment: I am also interested in this question. I'm also a bit confused by why a simple Google search didn't turn up any results from the statistics literature or references. Here are some slides I found from an econometrics MSc course: 

https://www.univ-orleans.fr/deg/masters/ESA/CH/Chapter2_MLE.pdf

Section 5 onwards seems to contains some of the results on the score function and Fisher info matrix for conditional log-likelihoods which you are looking for, but I haven't checked for asymptotics.

Comment: Thank you, I have already read those slides but I am not quite sure what the right answer is. From my understanding (which might be wrong), I assume that the equivalent is the expected information matrix, which is the expected value of the information matrix of the $t$-th observation with respect to $\Omega_{t-1}$  (using my notation). But due to the law of itered expectation, this should be equal to the unconditional expectation.  I looked in the usual textbooks, i.e. Hamiltion, Greene etc. but I haven't found an answer to that.

Comment: At first when I read the slides I felt that it seemed to cover the situations you were looking for. With respect to point 2 of your question, the conditional Fisher information for a single observation is specified on *slide 114*, the fact that $I_i(\theta) \neq I_j(\theta)$ for all $i, j$ on *slide 116* and the relation to average Fisher information and conditional Fisher information for one observation via iterated expectations on *slide 129*.

Comment: However, re-read your question, the deeper issue that jumps out at me in this case, and which might prevent using the slides to validate your algebraic derivations is that all the formulae and worked examples cover cross-sectional data. Whereas you are looking at a time-series setting, which merits its own set of considerations.

Comment: You are totally right. I leave this question open and hope that someone  has an explanation.